# Dynamic Gridlines on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The problem: Enable vertical or horizontal gridlines on a bar or column chart. My current implementation is not dynamic enough. Applying vertical gridline on column chart works fine but if you change the chart type to bar then its incorrect.

How do I make these vertical and horizontal gridlines adapt to the chart type?

```
jsfiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vG42/819/#

Comment: What's not working for your bar chart?

Comment: the 'verticalGridLines' variable turns on horizontal gridline on a bar and not vertical, if you change the chart type to 'colum' then its fine.

Comment: You can't use the variables that way, the variable name is just that, a name. In a bar graph the xAxis is displayed vertically, and in a column graph the xAxis is displayed horizontally. Which means that you have to set gridlines to 1 and 0 in the xAxis and yAxis based on this. Here is an example where I set the gridlines based on the chart type: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/5kft9rva/, press the button to toggle between bar and column graph.

Comment: Ah right, I see! makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a highcharts bar graph the `xAxis` is displayed *vertically*, and in a column graph the `xAxis` is displayed *horizontally*. Which means that you have to set gridlines to 1 and 0 in the `xAxis` and `yAxis` based on this. For example:

```
//For a column graph
chart_type = 'column'
xAxisGridLines = 0
yAxisGridLines = 1

//For a bar graph
chart_type = 'bar'
xAxisGridLines = 0
yAxisGridLines = 1
```

Here is a live example where I set the gridlines based on the chart type: **https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/5kft9rva**, press the button to toggle between bar and column graph.